# In ionic 2 i am getting this error while BluetoothSerial.isEnabled and BluetoothSerial.list()

Tags: bluetooth, ionic2, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image: Here screenshot of the error message]

Typescript Error
Property 'isEnabled' does not exist on type 'typeof BluetoothSerial'

```
BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
```

and also here

```
BluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {
```

Above is the error i get at runtime in ionic 2.
Thank you.

Comment: can you add your package.json to the question by [edit]ing?

Comment: i update my question now

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't working because a browser can't detect bluetooth devices try running the app on an actual device. Then use chrome://inspect through USB debugging to view the logs.

So i edited your code and its working. This is it. It shows paired devices not discovered devices.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BluetoothSerial} from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public deviceList:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private alertCtrl:AlertController,
              private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) {
    this.getAllBluetoothDevices();
  }

  // put BluetoothSerial inside a function, can't be called different
  getAllBluetoothDevices() {

    // async so keep everything in this method
    this.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(data => {
      if(data){
        this.bluetoothSerial.list().then(allDevices=> {
          // set the list to returned value
          if(allDevices.length > 0){
            this.deviceList=allDevices;
          }else{
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Bluetooth',
              subTitle: 'No devices found.',
              buttons: ['Dismiss']
            });
            alert.present();
          }
        });
      }
    }).catch(err=>{
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Bluetooth',
        subTitle: 'Check your bluetooth connection.',
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: i try to build the project, but it can't build the project and show's error as i mention

Comment: I have run the above code on an android device and using chrome://inspect i can view the Array of paired devices

Comment: i want to run above code in apk, and it's says check your bluetooth connection in android also.

Comment: Let me test it again

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem any how but yet i am not getting the error as above,
but now i am not getting the console.log("lists").

Can anyone say that code is running or not??
Because i am not getting any error but also not getting console log .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public working:string;
public var2: string ;
public lists = [];
public bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ) {
let me = this;
   me.getAllBluetoothDevices();
}

// put BluetoothSerial inside a function, can't be called different
getAllBluetoothDevices(){
let me = this;

    // async so keep everything in this method
   me.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
        // not sure of returning value, probably a boolean
        console.log("dont know what it returns"+data);

        // returns all the available devices, not just the unpaired ones
       me.bluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {
            // set the list to returned value
            me.lists = allDevices;
             console.log("lists");
             if(me.lists.length == 0){
               me.var2 = "could not find any bluetooth devices";
                console.log("lists");
            }


        });
    });
   }
}
```